# Call object inside RowDataPacket using Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

> **The code its about:**

```
con.query(`SET @row_num = 0; SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_number, userid, username, lvl FROM users ORDER BY lvl + 0 DESC`, async (err, rowss) => {
    if(err) throw err;
        console.log(rowss[0].userid);
    });
```

> **What i tried:**

I tried to use `rowss[0].userid` and `rowss.userid`. But non wanted to work for me. However, when i use `rowss` on its own, i get the following output:

```
[ OkPacket {
fieldCount: 0,
affectedRows: 0,
insertId: 0,
serverStatus: 10,
warningCount: 0,
message: '',
protocol41: true,
changedRows: 0 },
[ RowDataPacket {
  row_number: 1,
  userid: '123',
  username: 'test1#5245',
  lvl: '113' },
RowDataPacket {
  row_number: 2,
  userid: '456',
  username: 'test2#8272',
  lvl: '112' },
RowDataPacket {
  row_number: 3,
  userid: '789',
  username: 'test3#5873',
  lvl: '91' },
RowDataPacket {
  row_number: 4,
  userid: '012',
  username: 'test4#0581',
  lvl: '78' }.................
```

> **What i want:**

Call an object inside RowDataPacket and console.log it.
So what i want is basically when i typ:

```
console.log(rowss[0].username + ' - ' + rowss[0].lvl);
console.log(rowss[3].username + ' - ' + rowss[3].lvl);
```

That the output result is:

```
test1#5245 - 113 (Since this is the first row in the array).
test4#0581 - 78 (Since this is the 4th row).
```

> **My Problem:**

Whenever i try `console.log(rowss[0].username);` for example, i get `undefined`. This is for all the objects. so userid, lvl, etc too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enabled multiple statement as true while creating DB connection.This result in multiple ressultsets

> multipleStatements: true

Below resultset is response for the statment `SET @row_num = 0;`

```
OkPacket {
fieldCount: 0,
affectedRows: 0,
insertId: 0,
serverStatus: 10,
warningCount: 0,
message: '',
protocol41: true,
changedRows: 0 }
```

Data result for the select query is available in the second position of array 
select query data can be access as below

```
rowss[1][0].row_number
rowss[1][0].userid
rowss[1][0].lvl
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However i have one question about your answer. Why is it second position `[1]` and not the first one `[0]`? Wouldn't it be `[0][0]`?

Comment: You are executing mutiple query in single execution. Your select statement is in second position [1] so result is also in second position[1]. Set rownumber is considered as seperate query and it at first position [0]